# Two users asked same question in same day

Tags: support

I noticed these two questions [Question-1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115824/get-edit-form-for-a-node-using-drupal-get-form) and [Question-2](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115829/how-to-print-node-form-using-drupal-get-form) are same by two users. I don't know whether that was coincident or intentional.

My question is what should be done to these questions? Can we consider the recent post as duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention, the necessary action has been taken.

If you see more of the same in the future, please continue to flag them as duplicates so we can investigate.

Comment: Sure Clive, Thanks :)

Comment: I think flag w/ custom reason may be better in this case.